# How to check a string contains only digits and decimal points?

Tags: java, regex

For example I want to check that my when I split my string that the first part only contains numbers and decimal points.

I have done the following

```
String[] s1 = {"0.12.13.14-00000001-00000", "0.12.13.14-00000002-00000"};

        String[] parts_s1 = s1.split("-");
        System.out.println(parts_s1[0]);
        if(parts_s1[0].matches("[0-9]")
```

But thats only checking for numbers and not decimals. How can I also check for decimals in this? For example I want to check for 0.12.13.14 that it works and something like 0.12.13.14x will not work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the dot character in the regex as follows:

```
if(parts_s1[0].matches("[0-9.]*")) {     // match a string containing digits or dots
```

The `*` is to allow multiple digits/decimal points.

In case at least one digit/decimal point is required, replace `*` with `+` for one or more occurrences.

**EDIT:**

In case the regex needs to match (positive) decimal numbers (not just arbitrary sequences of digits and decimal points), a better pattern would be:

```
if(parts_s1[0].matches("\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {    // match a decimal number
```

Note that `\\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: And this will match an empty input also.

Comment: @anubhava True but that was not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I would think a regex to match `numbers and decimal points` should take care of that.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this regex:

```
\\d+(\\.\\d+)*
```

**Code:**

```
if(parts_s1[0].matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)*") {...}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply add a dot to the list of allowed characters:

```
if(parts_s1[0].matches("[.0-9]+")
```

This, however, would match strings that are composed entirely of dots, or have sequences of multiple dots.