# verifying if a string is a number

Tags: java, android

I want to parse a string to decimal using this method

```
 try {                
       Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
       exception.printStackTrace();                
    }
```

It throws exception if I put any letter in EditText or a number followed by a letter(so far so good),but when I enter a number followed by letter d or f(example 2.1or 2.1f) it doesen't throw exception.The method treats 2.1d string or 2.1f string as 2.1float or 2.1double and return the double as 2.1d or 2.1f and the program crashes.
I also tried to parse the string using :

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(str);

Double.valueOf(str);

 Double doubleObject = new Double(str);
 double number = doubleObject.doubleValue();

StringUtils.isNumeric(str);
```

and the result was the same.

In  the end I did it using `if(str.contains(d)||str.contains(f))throw new Exception(...)`

Is there another method or another way to do this without using if.

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833364/how-to-check-a-string-contains-only-digits-and-decimal-points

Comment: in xml add input type as number if you want to type only number

Comment: May not be very neat, but if it is only those 2 letters you have a problem with, then make use of the Replace function to replace the 'f' and the 'd' with ""

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way if I were you.

```
Double numberVar = Double.parseDouble(yourEditText.getText().toString());

if(new Double(numberVar) istanceof Double){
    return true;
}
```

Very clean and just because a string contains a 0 or 1 or any other number does not mean it does not contain an a or an I.

Answer (score -2):

You should use Long to parse a number. Because Double is a floating point number and it does not throw Exception for Floating value and also **d** represent the value in Double so still it will not throw Exception. You should use Long for this.

**Like this**

```
Long.parseLong(str);
```

but still it will accept **l** with the no. so then you can add an if condition before parsing

```
if(!str.contains("l"))
{
    Long.parseLong(str);
}
else
{
    // it is not a number.
}
```

another solution is that put **inputType** inside the `EditText`

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: "_example 2.1or 2.1f_" ... an you want to parse that in a Long ?

Comment: If you want to check decimal number then do not use Long, double is good for that. but instead of this logic you should use inputType="numberDecimal". that will work surely.