# Nullsafe Long valueOf

Tags: parsing, numberformatexception, java

Imagine the following scenario
`Long critId = Long.valueOf(criteriaIdentifier);`

If the view is initially loaded `criteriaIdentifier` may be null, afterwards I set the value depending of the `selectedItem` in the JSF View.

However, `Long.valueOf(criteriaIdentifier)` throws a `NumberFormatException` - If the string cannot be parsed as a long(i.e `null`).

I've thought of default setting the Id to default `-1`, but I wanted to know if there is better practice .

*PS: technically the `criteriaIdentifier` can't be -1, since these values are set from the Database, with a Sequence Generator, so I should know -1 was the default value and properly do the default operations*

Comment: `NumberFormatException` - If the string cannot be parsed as a long. Editted

Comment: If `null` is an expected value in some cases, perform a null check in before or sourround with try/catch

Comment: @AndréStannek it should be never NULL, and if it was, i perform a default action

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a string contains only digits and decimal points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833364/how-to-check-a-string-contains-only-digits-and-decimal-points)

Comment: All the duplicate flags, did you even read my problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `NumberUtils` from Apache Commons. It's null-safe and you can optionally specify a default value.

Example:

```
NumberUtils.toLong(null) = 0L
NumberUtils.toLong("")   = 0L
NumberUtils.toLong("1")  = 1L

NumberUtils.toLong(null, 1L) = 1L
NumberUtils.toLong("", 1L)   = 1L
NumberUtils.toLong("1", 0L)  = 1L
```

For more info, check the [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 7):

When we say nullSafe we usually expect to receive a `null` from the API when passing `null` to it, not a `0` or `-1` or any other value.

The intention is that the API does not break in case of receiving `null`, but simply returning `null`.

For this, use `createLong` static method of the `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`.

CAUSION*:
This throws NumberFormatException if the input String is NOT `null` and is NOT numeric.

CAUSION**: since 3.1 it handles hex (0Xhhhh) and octal (0ddd) notations. N.B. a leading zero means octal; spaces are not trimmed.

Sample:

```
NumberUtils.createLong(null) --> null
NumberUtils.createLong("1") --> 1
NumberUtils.createLong("hi") --> NumberFormatException
NumberUtils.createLong(" 11") --> NumberFormatException (does not trim)
NumberUtils.createLong("023") --> 19 (leading 0 means octal)
NumberUtils.createLong("0x23") --> 35 (leading 0x means hex)
```

Answer (score 5):

`Long.valueOf(null)` will throw `NumberFormatException`, not `NullPointerException`.

In Java 8, you have the possibility to declaratively choose a default evaluation for a nullable inline, e.g.

```
Long.valueOf(
    Optional.ofNullable(criteriaIdentifier).orElseGet(() -> "-1")
)
```

It's a little verbose, but will allow you to default to `-1l` if `criteriaIdentifier` is `null` (no need for additional dependencies).

API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Comment: is there a Java 7 solution to this too?

Comment: @0x45 unfortunately no, there isn't as such. `Optional` comes with Java 8. You can either build your own util or use external libraries (or just check for `null` explicitly and assigning a value).

Comment: You shouldn't use Optional this way, just use a ternary expression, or do an explicit null check using an if.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming criteriaIdentifier is a String.
You could use
[org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.toLong(String, long)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong-java.lang.String-long-) which gives you the default value if the String argument is null.
Or you use [org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.toLong(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong-java.lang.String-) which returns zero if the String is null.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your scenario but usually there are ways to avoid such problems.

Generally setting IDs to -1 is a common practice but I don't think it is a good one. You know that -1 is not a possible value in your scenario but considering just the type Long it is a valid value. So everywhere in the code you will need to implement tests like if `id!=-1` which makes the code harder to understand and generally the `null` value is more suitable for that scenario - Long object without a value.

If it was up to me for example in the method that receives an ID and waits a valid ID if I get null I would throw an exception and let the caller of the method handle that. If it is a web API for example (otherwise why would you get a String?) then you can throw an HTTP error. Or if you want to handle bad arguments then you better return null or use null as default value.

Comment: The service etc don't care what IDs put in.